# Regex for table search string with and without commas

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having trouble finding a regex solution for a table search result.
I tried the regex below, but it did not work as expected.

First

```
const regex = new RegExp(
  searchTerm
    ?.toString()
    .replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&")
    .replace(/\s+/g, "|") + ",?",
  "gi"
);
```

Second

```
const regex = new RegExp(
  searchTerm
    ?.toString()
    .replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&")
    .replace(/\s+/g, "|") + "|,",
  "gi"
);
```

Third

```
const regex = new RegExp(searchTerm.replace(/,/g, "\\s*,\\s*"), "gi");
```

I can highlight the exact search result, but I also want to highlight the string with commas.

[image]

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You could add regex [character classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes) like punctuation and symbols with a predefined length (0-1 in the example) after each char of the search term.

This would allow a wider range for possible results and returns you the matches to highlight them.

```js
search.oninput = function() {
  if (this.value) {
    // character classes punctuation and symbols can be behind every char
    const possibleNextchar = "[\\p{P}\\p{S}]?",
      toEscape = '.^$*+?()[{\\|';
    const re = new RegExp(
      '(' + this.value.replace(/./gu,
        (char) => (toEscape.includes(char) ? "\\" + char : char) + possibleNextchar 
      ) + ')', "gu");
    console.log(re);
    table.querySelectorAll("td").forEach(td => {
      re.lastIndex = -1;
      console.log([...td.innerText.matchAll(re)]);
    })
  }
}
search.oninput();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search" value="247">
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>$ 2,477.00</td>
    <td>122477123</td>
    <td>24/7</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```